# Merge produce an empty dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I'm new to R and I'm facing some issues with the merge function. When I tried to merge two data frames, I got an empty data frame!

This is the code I'm using:

```
pb <- merge(dashed_results, participants_background,
        by=c("Time.results.were.received", "MD5.hash.of.participant.s.IP.address", "Item.number"))
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. To help others help you, can you please include the tables, or relevant small portions of the that demonstrate the problem, in your question. As text please, formatted as code

Comment: Do both the tables have the column names you mentioned in by = c()? If yes, there are no common rows that can be merged. hence returns the empty data.frame. if you are trying to combine two tables one over the other but not joining, then try bind_rows() from dplyr package. As piterbarg mentioned, example tables would help us to help you.

Comment: Hi, my main table has these columns: Time.results.were.received, MD5.hash.of.participant.s.IP.address, Item.number, PennElementName, Value. and I want to merge two columns from my original results file that have some participants information: group, nationality. I already used the spread function to got them, the only problem now in with the merge function.